# Why can I modify an object through a raw pointer but not a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

So, I would like to use a function that modifies an object through a `shared_ptr`.

I've got this class `Foo`:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    bool i = false;

public:
    void activate()
    {
        i = true;
    }

    bool isActive()
    {
        return i;
    }
};
```

Nothing too fancy. My goal is to modify a `Foo` object through a pointer, like so:

```
Foo foo;

std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptrfoo = std::make_shared<Foo>(foo);
ptrfoo->activate();

// "foo.isActive" returns false here
```

Sadly, `foo.isActive` returns `false` when I want it to return `true`. But the thing is, it works with raw pointers:

```
Foo foo;

Foo* ptrfoo = &foo;
ptrfoo->activate();

// "foo.isActive" returns true here
```

So why does that happen, and can I modify the object through a `shared_ptr`? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart pointers are owning pointers.  Because they own the memory they point to when you do

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptrfoo = std::make_shared<Foo>(foo);
```

you don't get a pointer to `foo` but instead you get a pointer to an object that is a copy of `foo`.  Anything you do to `ptrfoo` will not effect `foo`.  This is one of the main differences between raw pointers and smart pointers.  You can get a smart pointer to act like a raw pointer, but that is a lot of work and non owning raw pointers are okay so it's not really worth trying to modify smart pointers to get that behavior.

Comment: So should I just use raw pointers in this case or is there a better solution?

Comment: @Khanoa is there any need for the pointer at all? You may be able to pass a reference to `foo` around.

Comment: @Khanoa That depends entirely on the use case.  I can't really make any suggestions without seeing what your code is doing.

Comment: I'd say this is tangent to the answer. The real issue is simply that they mis-used `std::make_shared`. You give it constructor parameters that allow the object to be constructed directly into the `shared_ptr`, and in passing `foo`, they just invoked the copy constructor (That's the matching constructor). If they just wanted a shared pointer to a default Foo, `std::make_shared<Foo>()` would have sufficed.

Comment: @sweenish They wanted the `shared_ptr` to point to `foo`, that's why they passed `foo` to `make_shared`.

Comment: **"My goal is to modify a Foo object through a pointer"** The MRE is just that. It still wouldn't change the fact that you barely mentioned the actual issue with their code. I'm also just noticing the last bit of your answer. I disagree with that as well. They act like raw pointers just fine for the basic operations.

Comment: I missed the "like so," so I get how it can be they want that foo specifically. In that case, I think I'd forego `std::make_shared` altogether. `auto ptrFoo = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(&foo);` I do still stand by my original point that the answer doesn't actually catch what's wrong with the code in the question, though.

Comment: @sweenish `auto ptrFoo = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(&foo);` is going to explode on you.  When `ptrFoo` goes out of scope it is going to try and delete a stack pointer.

Comment: That's on the MRE. I obviously prefer `std::make_shared`, but if that's really what they want, then those are the consequences. It fits, then, that the better answer is to explain not just a smart pointer is, but how they should have properly used `std::make_shared`.

Comment: "owning pointers" no, classes that somehow simulate ptr syntaxes; I *hate* that "smart ptr" terminology (like "copy elision") but I guess we are stuck with it.

Answer (score 1):

In the first block, the `shared_ptr` points to a copy of `foo`.
In the second block, the pointer points to `foo`.

You can verify that by using:

```
std::cout << "Address of foo: " << &foo << std::endl;
std::cout << "Pointer from shared_ptr: " << ptrfoo->get() << std::endl;
```